# How to pass multiple form values as parameters in ajax call?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

this is the code i tried:

```
function show(date,meal){
var parameters = 'q='+date '&m='+meal;
var argUrl = 'meal1.php';
    $.ajax({
        url: argUrl,
          type: 'POST',
          data: parameters,
          success: function (str) {
          $('#txtHint').html(str);  
          //alert(parameters);              
         } 
    });
 }
```

**My form**:

```
<form method="post">
<input type="text" id="datewise" name="datewise"  value="" class="form- control input-datepicker-close"  placeholder="dd/mm/yy" >

<select id="mealplan" name="mealplan" class="form-control" onchange="shownoofroom(this.value);">
<option value=""> Select </option>
    <?php  $sql = "select *from mean_plan";
    $retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
    if(! $retval ){
      die('Could not get data: ' . mysql_error());
      echo 'Could not get data: ' . mysql_error();
     }
      while($row = mysql_fetch_array($retval,MYSQL_ASSOC)){ //roll id if
     //$roll_id= $row['roleid'];
  ?>
  <option value="<?php echo $row['meanplan']?>"><?php echo $row['meanplan']?></option>

  <?php
   }
    ?>
 </select>

<input type="buttton" class="btn btn-info btn-primary " onclick="show('<?php $_POST['datewise'];?>','<?php $_POST['mealplan'];?>')name="submit">
</form>
<div id="txtHint">
```

Is this the correct method to pass parameters to a function..
Or else how i can pass form values in the onclick event and store it in function variable.

Comment: it'll be easier if you use jQuery. `.serialize()` will get all values on your form

Comment: Am i right in onclick() part.....

Comment: i'm getting an error message

Answer (score 2):

this is ok

```
function show(date,meal){

var argUrl = 'meal1.php';
    $.ajax({
        url: argUrl,
          type: 'POST',
          data: {
                    date:date,
                    meal:meal
                     },
          success: function (str) {
          $('#txtHint').html(str);  
          //alert(parameters);              
         } 
    });
 }
```

Comment: what about the button call...onclick=show('<?php $_POST['val1']?>','<?php $_POST['val2']?>')

Comment: show('<?php echo $_POST['val1']?>','<?php echo $_POST['val2']?>')

Comment: is it right to call a function in this manner

Comment: i'm getting an error as undefined index $datewise,$mealplan  in onclick=show('<?php $_POST['datewise']','<?php $_POST['mealplan']')

Comment: first change `show('<?php $_POST['datewise']','<?php $_POST['mealplan']') ` to `show('<?php echo $_POST['datewise']','<?php echo $_POST['mealplan']') ` and than check

Comment: nope its not working i'm getting an error like this..........................     Notice: Undefined index: datewise in C:\wamp\www\assets\meal_plan.php on line 170 Call Stack #TimeMemoryFunctionLocation 10.0010150792{main}( )..\meal_plan.php:0 ','

Comment: i'm not getting the value instead...

Comment: without the form submission how can i get the value...I think its not possible...so whats the next step to get those values...